# Is there a Timetable Calendar with Holidays which i can download or generate?

Tags: download, calendar, timetable

I am searching for a complete Timetable Dimension.
What should be included?

- Days
- Month
- Week
- Holidays(for several countries)

I searched a long time, and I think the difficult thing are the holidays.

What is my goal?

- I want to use it for Stock Price Prediction.

If anybdody knows where to download a Timetable/Calendar or someone can show me a Code (Code language not relevant, because i use KNIME as universal tool) it would save me a lot of work.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AdamTheEmperor, is there any update on this? Did you sort it out? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As a base, you may want to use a KNIME node to generate a calendar table: https://hub.knime.com/knime/extensions/org.knime.features.base/latest/org.knime.time.node.create.createdatetime.CreateDateTimeNodeFactory

For the CW number, there is also KNIME workflow available related to this node.

Finally, Python might be your best friend for the holidays: https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays